# The container does not exist in the task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

on my CI i have configured the deploy on the AWS ECS environment via bash script

```
**deploy.sh**
[...]

aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://./deploy/skeleton.json

TASK_DEFINITION_ARN=$(aws ecs --output text list-task-definitions --family-prefix "${PROJECT_NAME}" --sort DESC --query "taskDefinitionArns[0]")

aws ecs update-service \
    --cluster "${PROJECT_NAME}" \
    --service "${PROJECT_NAME}" \
    --task-definition "${TASK_DEFINITION_ARN}" \
    --force-new-deployment \
    --deployment-configuration "maximumPercent=200,minimumHealthyPercent=100" \
    --desired-count ${DESIRED_COUNT}

[...]
```

and

```
    **skeleton.json**
{
    "family": "backend",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/XXXX",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::0000000:role/XXXX",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "containerDefinitions":
        [{
            "name": "csharp",
            "essential": true,
            "environment":[{
                "name" : "CONNECTIONSTRINGS__Redis",
                "value" : "XXXX"
                },
                {
                "name" : "CONNECTIONSTRINGS__Database",
                "value" : "XXX"
                },
                {
                "name" : "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
                "value" : "XXX"
                }],
            "image": "00000000.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prj/backend:643105ef",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/backend/",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "csharp"
                }
            }
        }],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "256",
    "memory": "512"
}
```

when i try to deploy with update-service the cli answer with:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: The container backend does not exist in the task definition.
```

but if i change in the json the container name from **csharp** to **backend**, the deploy works.

is that a bug?
thx

Comment: maybe your definition is in different version of the task definition which you try to deploy?

Comment: In my case, I have added !sub function and it also not working. so I have added static name

Answer (score 44):

The container `name` you define in task_definition must match with the one in ecs_service's load_balancer configuration container_name. This will allow the load balancer to dynamically map the container ports and attach it to target groups.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This helped thanks.  My issue was when copying a HowTo the family_name and container_definations name were the same in the task_definition and the service container_name was referencing the family name (which I had changed)

Answer (score 12):

I'm answering this old question to point out some notes for the Googlers.

It seems that there are two problems related to this error message.

The first one is that the error itself is misguided, since the reason behind it [is not related to the task definition directly](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1276#issuecomment-513746198) and actually this is the Load Balancer (LB) complaining about the container name, it is trying to find in the task definition.

As the problem itself, While creating a LB, `containerName` is passed as a prop and in most cases it is one of the container names on the first task definition revision. Changing container names that are used while creating a LB, via creating new task revisions, would probably result in [this error](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=679456#679456).

In this case, recreating the service and/or task definition would probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

ECS allows you to define many containers inside one `task definition`, so the ELB needs to know what container to direct the traffic to, in order to do that, it stores the name of the container you set it up with during creation.

[image]

If you are getting this error, you are probably not including a container with the same `Container Name` so it's complaining of not knowing what to connect to inside that new task definition.

## TL;DR

Rename the container `name` inside the `task definition` to be the same as the container defined in the currently running (or last successfully deployed) task definition.

[image]